# How to live update a variable, and have it affect something?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, d3.js, graph

another question for you guys:

I have my `index.html` file, which has a script and function (function is triggered by a button):

```
function myFunction() {
  domainA = domainA - 5;
  domainB = domainB - 5;
}
```

These variables are defined in a `.js` file as such:

```
var domainA = 500;
var domainB = 1000;
```

These variables are in a d3 function (d3.js v4) as the scale domain of a graph like so:

```
this._xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([domainA, domainB])
    .range([0, this._canvasWidth - 20]);
```

The code works normally with the pre-defined variables of `domainA` and `domainB`, however when I press my button to change the values of these two variables, my d3 graph does not change.

Is this an issue with the graph not being able to be live updated? Is this issue possible to hurdle with JQuery? Again, any help is greatly appreciated!

*QUICK UPDATE* One solution that is probable is to reload the page once the variable is updated. I cannot support this solution in my code, because reloading the page will lose some data on my code.

Comment: I wanted to upload my code so that people could see my graph and what it looks like, however this graph is part of a big web application that requires a lot of setup, and cannot be uploaded to github for easy view. Again, apologies for the littleness of resources I provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to re-render your d3 code after the click event. I would make a render method and call it at load time and then also call it after your data changes.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean about calling it at load time...could you maybe elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Also, d3 does not have a render method. I need to use React to do this, correct?

Comment: @a.mosallaei, no you would create your own render method. something like:
```
function render() {
   this._xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([domainA, domainB])
    .range([0, this._canvasWidth - 20]);
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear!